# Get customer invite token

Tags: shopify

Annoyingly, Shopify does not allow registration until completing checkout. I want people to be able to register *before* buying so that I can use their logged-in state to trigger some template changes, discounts, etc.

I've worked out how to add customer accounts using the API, but this effectively only sets the account up for activation. I would have to manually approve each registration from the Shopify admin panel. Not cool!

Invitation emails contain a URL which follows this pattern:
http://shopname.myshopify.com/account/activate/14e18ab6887f4f61d8fb038bb956be99

Does anybody know if there's a way to get that activation token with the API so I can send out activation emails of my own, straight after adding the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to create customer accounts and send the activation emails automatically. This is an issue we're aware of and are looking to fix in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I found a way around this using a Ruby script – if anybody is interested in seeing it, leave a message here and I'll post.

Comment: yeah can you please share ?

Answer (score 1):

This is available in the admin now.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email invite now from the Shopify admin, but this is still manual. You have to go into each customer and click a link to send the invite.

There is an app available now called 'Automatic Account Invites' in Shopify that will automatically send the invites when a customer is created in Shopify.

[Automatic Account Invites for Shopify](https://apps.shopify.com/automatic-account-invites)